# spacy error : some strings.json not found

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

After installing Spacy like tutorials,i was trying a small code like this :

> import spacy
>   nlp = spacy.load('en') #same this for spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

this code was implemented on windows10 on different virtual environements always having a problem.
I had this error :

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\wael\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\lib\\site-packages\\en_core_web_sm\\en_core_web_sm-2.0.0\\vocab\\strings.json'
```

any help ?

Comment: Do any of the suggestions in this thread help? https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2902

Comment: I found the solution in here : https://spacy.io/usage/

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution in here : https://spacy.io/usage/
There are a lot of section about known issues.

Comment: Please share how you solved your problem in greater detail. It may be helpful to others facing the same issue.